# Metadata files for references not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I use MSBuild Version 14.0.

Following the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx), I defined my own `Build` task like this:

```
<Target Name="Build" 
        Inputs="@(Compile)"
        Outputs="MyLibrary.dll">

        <Csc 
            Sources="@(Compile)"
            Resources="@(EmbeddedResource)" 
            References="@(Reference);@(ProjectReference)" 
            OutputAssembly="MyLibrary.dll"/>
</Target>
```

In one of my `ItemGroup`s, I added the following references:

```
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
```

However, the build failed because of these errors:

```
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'System' could not be found [C:\MyLibrary.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Core' could not be found C:\MyLibrary.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Runtime.Serialization' could not be found [C:\MyLibrary.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Xml' could not be found [C:\MyLibrary.csproj]
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** I think MSBuild threw that error because all of the DLLs mentioned in the error messages above are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\`, instead of inside the folder containing my `.csproj` file. I would prefer not to copy and paste those references into my project folder. What should I do to ensure that those DLLs can be correctly located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do to ensure that those DLLs can be correctly located?

After check the documentation [How to: Build Incrementally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx) more carefully, I found that we should include the file type suffix `.dll` in those references, otherwise, Csc.exe compiler could not find those files. So you `ItemGroup` should be:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.dll" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core.dll">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will give this a shot and write an update.